# Help me! I'm trapped

Tags: cipher

```
Can zpv tgcf wklvC Mw ymjwj gt4utk v10 1pm 2qn0nI
```

> All they told me about this typewriter is that it uses some sort of caeser cipher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cipher is

> Can you read this? Is there anyone out the there?

Which uses a

> Caesar cipher with the base code 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?', with the rotation starting at 0 and incrementing by one with each word